# Spring Data Neo4j - Howto limit all queries to a subset of nodes (depending on the request header)

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

in our project we are using Spring Data Neo4j and have a lot of queries. When we want to update a node with new data, we do not actually update the node, instead we create a new node with a *PREVIOUS* relation to the current node. Furthermore we can make revisions. These are nodes with a *CONTAINS* relation to the nodes belonging to this revision.
Now the client passes in the request header an ID of a revision and the executed queries should then only contain the nodes which are either the newest (so no *PREVIOUS* relation exists there) or are part of the revision. We want to limit the queried nodes to a subset of nodes.

Now I don't want to change every query manually and I think that there is an easier way but unfortunately I haven't found it anywhere after a long search.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your model looks like the one below and follows your description, this should do it.

Assuming a parameter `ID`

```
MATCH (r:Revision {ID: $id})
MATCH (n) 
WHERE (n)<-[:CONTAINS]-(r)
      OR NOT (n)-[:PREVIOUS]->()
RETURN n
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but my actual question is where to put this query so that I do not have to modify every single query already written. So for example if I have a repository with some defined queries, is there an easy way to limit the results  to the nodes that get matched by the query you provided? I don't want to change all queries manually in every repository if there is another solution.